# CMS which allows for a big database, but simpler than WordPress

Tags: cms, self-hosted

I want to make a site where I can upload *all my work ever*. This means documents, images, videos, as well as scraped data from my social media accounts. I want to make some posts public, and some private so I can use it as a personal archive as well as a blog.

This is obviously nothing that WordPress can't do, but I feel like it might be a bit bulky with it's clunky admin panel, etc.

Is there a simpler tool I could use for this kind of thing?

Comment: Well the size could be anything I suppose. I haven't collected the data yet, just planning the project.

Comment: You probably want to self-host this, right? Any restrictions regarding server/programming languages? Does license/price matter?

Comment: @unor yeah, self-hosted. Open to learning a language, but I'd be interested in hearing the benefits of using anything other than PHP which seems to be the standard for this kind of thing. And free is preferred but if there's considerable benefits over WordPress I'd be willing  to pay a small amount.

Comment: Okay. Could you describe what exactly you need for the blogging part, and maybe elaborate on why WordPress is not a suitable candidate?

Comment: Have a sniff around http://cmsmatrix.org/ Whatever you want in the way of a CMS, it is there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[GetSimple CMS](http://get-simple.info/)**, which is a lightweight, open source, PHP-based, database-less CMS. It allows you to write posts, upload files, add components and plugins. See the [screenshots](http://get-simple.info/start/screenshots/) and a [live demo](http://get-simple.info/demo/).

Answer (score 0):

[Rubedo](http://www.rubedo-project.org/) is good candidate for your project. This CMs is based on big data base MongoDB. You can manage documents, images, videos and audio files.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Can you make "some posts public, and some private" with it? Any experiences with Rubedo you could share? Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer. Thanks in advance!